# Can a game be a subject in the sentence?

Tags: grammar

> Where is the basketball game?
>  (A Korean middle school English
>   textbook)

The sentence seems to ask where they are playing basketball. I’d like to know if the sentence is proper and natural, for I’m not familiar with it that a game is used as a subject in sentences.

Comment: Is there any reason why do you think _game_ cannot be the subject of a sentence? It is a noun and, like any other nouns, it can be the subject of a sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any string of words that can be used as a noun phrase can be the subject of a sentence. It's strictly a matter of grammatical structure, not the content of the noun phrase. For example:

> **The basketball game** was fun.
>   **The football game** is on channel 5.
>   **Water polo games** bore me.
>   **Ice hockey games** are usually violent.